# MySQL: str_to_date function showing incorrect datetime value

Tags: mysql, laravel

Its strange but i can't understand what exactly is happening. I am just trying to update my column value by calculate the difference between two dates. I have two columns having date `column_45` and `column_14` both columns having date with format `4/8/2011` and `4/8/2009` now i am calculating the diffrence between both dates with `DATEDIFF()` function and to correct the date format i am using `STR_TO_DATE()` function. Everything working fine when i am running query from `phpmyadmin` and when that same query i am running from my laravel project its showing error:

> Incorrect datetime value: 'No' for function str_to_date (SQL: UPDATE `define_testing` set column_1637 = DATEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE(`column_45`,"%m/%d/%Y"),STR_TO_DATE(`column_14`,"%m/%d/%Y")) where id > 1)

I know there are some string value in my column but it should show that same in phpmyadmin also but its working fine in phpmyadmin.

My Table:

[image]

MyQuery:
[image]

Exact MySql Query:

```
UPDATE `define_testing` set `column_1637` = DATEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE(`column_45`,"%m/%d/%Y"),STR_TO_DATE(`column_14`,"%m/%d/%Y")) where id > 1
```

Can any one tell me what is wrong?

Comment: You really have your columns named like this?  That's going to be a nightmare down the road.

Comment: this is temporary table..columns name will be dynamic in my case...

Comment: As you can see in the error message, one of the date values is causing the problem. Can you output your query manually and add it to the question? The exact query, which gets executed would be helpful.

Comment: check my updates.

Comment: datevalue causing an error because some data in the form of string `No`, `Active` but it is working fine in phpmyadmin..

Comment: i think some of people not able to understand the problem..

Comment: That's not the exact code, which gets fired. Please run the code and store the query in a variable, use this var in like this: `DB::select($var);` and additionally output this var and post it here so we can also see the dates. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sir, this is the exact query which is running..i am updating the value on the behalf of existing columns.

Comment: this is exactly what i am looking for .. please add answer as soon as possible sir.. thanku

Answer (score 0):

Try `DB::statement` for [raw queries](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/database) that return boolean.

```
DB::statement('UPDATE '. $table .' set column_'. $colCount .' = DATEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE('.$value->col_one.',"%m/%d/%Y"),STR_TO_DATE('.$value->col_two.',"%m/%d/%Y")) where id > 1');
```